# How to clear cookies and cache data in react-native-webview

Tags: react-native, webview

I am using react-native-webview for react-native-azure-ad-2 login authentication. Webview saves the login credentials once user logged in and it perform automatically login on relaunch. I want to clear the old user credentials when user relaunch the application again so that a new user can perform the login with new credentials.

Comment: What react-native version are you using?